# Output product custom field (image) in woocommerce emails

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Products in my WooCommerce store have a custom field added through Advanced Custom Field plugin `store_email_logo`. This field is an image field and I can't figure out how to output the image in a WooCommerce email.

I tried the code below but it's not working, it outputs some number instead of an image.

```
// Tested on WooCommerce version 2.6.x and 3+ — For simple products only.
add_action('woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'wcv_ingredients_email_logo', 10, 4);
function wcv_ingredients_email_logo( $order,  $sent_to_admin,  $plain_text,  $email ){
    foreach($order->get_items() as $item_values){
        // Get the product ID for simple products (not variable ones)
        $product_id = $item_values['product_id'];
        $output = get_post_meta( $product_id, 'store_email_logo', true );
        echo ' ' . $output . '<br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: WHAT does it output? "some number" could be anything

Comment: I just checked it's data id: "42"

Comment: `get_post_meta` retrieves a post meta field, in this case, your product. The `store_email_logo` metafield is outputting `42`. So there is another step you need to take to grab the logo with that ID, or the values in that field are incorrect.

Comment: I'm betting '42' is the media ID and you just need to do. `get_media_item()` to fetch the file itself. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_media_item/

Comment: it is, but where should I add get_media_item()?

Comment: I gave you the wrong function. It should be `wp_get_attachment_image()`. `$media_id = get_post_meta( $product_id, 'store_email_logo', true );` then under it
`$output = wp_get_attachment_image($media_id);`

Comment: thanks, but it's not working for me, this is my code now: `add_action('woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'wcv_ingredients_email_logo', 10, 4);
function wcv_ingredients_email_logo( $order,  $sent_to_admin,  $plain_text,  $email ){
    foreach($order->get_items() as $item_values){
        // Get the product ID for simple products (not variable ones)
        $media_id = get_post_meta( $product_id, 'store_email_logo', true );
        $output = wp_get_attachment_image($media_id);
        echo ' ' . $output . '<br>';
    }
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "number" that is displaying is the ID of the image that is associated to your product. There are a couple of functions that can output the actual image for you. I am quite partial to the [`wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id, $size)`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/) functionality.

```
add_action('woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'wcv_ingredients_email_logo', 10, 4);
function wcv_ingredients_email_logo( $order,  $sent_to_admin,  $plain_text,  $email ){
    foreach($order->get_items() as $item_values){
        // Get the product ID for simple products (not variable ones)
        $product_id     = $item_values['product_id']; //get the product ID
        $image_id       = get_post_meta( $product_id, 'store_email_logo', true ); //get the image ID associated to the product
        $image_src      = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image_id, 'full' )[0]; //get the src of the image - you can use 'full', 'large', 'medium', or 'thumbnail' here,
        $image          = '<img src="'.$image_src.'">'; //create the img element
        echo $image . '<br>'; //echo the image
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I tried the code but now I'm getting broken image icon in the mail instead of the image.

Comment: @MarkoI. ah - i forgot to add a `[0]` at the end of `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` _(it returns an array of [source, width, height])_ - i've edited my answer - give it another try?

Comment: Hm nothing is showing now - not even a broken image icon

Comment: ah sorry, it works, i made an issue with formatting

Comment: Oh rad - I am glad to hear :)

Comment: Appreciate it :) Do you maybe know how to add this image to the email header? the current hook is adding the image after order table. I would like to add it to header. I found wc email hooks for header: `woocommerce_email_header ($email_heading, $email)` and tried replacing it but I'm getting internal server error

Comment: @MarkoI. yeah the `woocommerce_email_header` won't work due to the lack of the `$order` object inside the arguments. I think the highest placed action that includes the `$order` argument would be `woocommerce_email_order_details` If you want to attach it inside the actual header, you will probably need to adjust the email template entirely - good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

try the below code. It may help you.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', 'action_wc_email_order_details' 50, 4 );
function action_wc_email_order_details( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ){
// Get the Order ID (WooCommerce retro-compatibility)
$order_id = method_exists( $order, 'get_id' ) ? $order->get_id() : $order->id;

// Get "store_email_logo" custom field value
$store_email_logo= get_post_meta($order_id, "store_email_logo", true );

// Display "serial" custom field value
echo '<img src="'.__('store_email_logo', 'woocommerce') . $store_email_logo. '" alt="image">';
}
```

Comment: thanks I tried the code but I'm getting broken image icon in the mail